How to resolve authentication issue when calling protected API routes from another protected API route in Next.js?
I am working on a Next.js application and facing an authentication issue when calling a protected API route from another protected API route. Additionally, I am unable to call a protected API route from a server action. Here's a detailed explanation of the problem:
/api/get-order-detail/[id]
export async function GET(req:NextRequest){
 const res = await axios.get(`${DOMAIN}/api/get-token`); // API Failure
}

/api/get-token
export async function GET(req:NextRequest){
 //logic for generating token
}

/actions/get-order-detail
export const getOrderDetail = async()=>{
 const res = await axios.get(`${DOMAIN}/api/get-token`); // API Failure
}


I have two protected API routes in my Next.js application, secured
using NextAuth.
When I make a request from the client to the server, the necessary
cookies are sent along with the request, and everything works fine.
However, when I try to make a server-to-server call from one
protected API route to another, the request fails due to missing
cookies, resulting in an authentication failure.

What I know:

The initial client-to-server request includes all necessary cookies,
which ensures successful authentication.
The server-to-server call lacks these cookies, leading to the
authentication failure.

Logs : 
{
cookies: RequestCookies{}
Authorization:'Bearer undefined'
}
 

What I've tried:

Manually adding cookies to the server-to-server request headers, but
I am unsure how to properly do this in Next.js. This was working in local but not in production (Vercel).

How can I correctly pass authentication cookies when making server-to-server requests in a Next.js application?

Hey, can you provide an example how you tried to set the cookies manually?

It was working fine in local but in prod.
const session = cookies.get("authjs.session-token")?.value;
headers: {
"Content-Type": "application/json",
Cookie: authjs.session-token=${session},
},

I see in production, the key becomes _Secure-authjs.session-token

It's really hard to understand what's failing here without information on how your cookies look like in the browser, what domain they belong to, how authjs meddles in here, how your middleware looks like. That said, I also don't understand how a "request from the client to the server" is working fine, but at the same time the axios call is described as faulty. I expected the axios call to be that "request from client to server". On "how to pass cookies from server-to-server requests": just use delegation. The other kind of you problem is a tad too obscure atm.

For the /api/get-order-detail/[id] endpoint, your assumption is correct: when you run a new request in there, the cookies won't carry over automatically, you'ld have to add them. Note this can be avoided by simple delegation to /api/get-token respl invoking this method manually:
import {GET as getToken} fronm '../../get-token/route';

export async function GET(req: NextRequest){
  const tokenRequst = new NextRequest(`${DOMAIN}/api/get-token`) // url might not even matter in most cases b/c you're invoking the handler directly
  req.cookies.set({name: "refreshToken", value: req.cookies.get("refreshToken")})
  const tokenRes = await getToken(req);
}

When invoking the token directly from the client side, you have to set the cookies in the ordinary way. E.g. for axios:
const response = await axios.get(`${DOMAIN}/api/get-token`, {
  headers: {
    Cookie: 'refreshToken=myRefreshToken'
  },
})

If this is failing, you need to provide more details on how you're setting and reading the cookies.
Oh, another thing. If api handlers only work in dev-mode, it's probably Next.js wrongly creating static versions of them when building for production. You have to add export const dynamic = 'force-dynamic'; to the according handler file: https://nextjs.org/docs/app/api-reference/file-conventions/route-segment-config

Next.js will automatically send the cookies if request is sent from the client, So passing cookie from client side is not required at all.

@JagdishPadeliya In fact, not Next.js, but the brower does. But only if the value is stored in your cookies. My guess was that myRefreshToken (or whatever you want to convey) doesn't reside there..

@JagdishPadeliya I've added my comment with a more elaborate on how to achieve delegation with a new Request and a new cookie. Still not sure that covers all your questions though.
